# Why Virtual keyboard does not trigger AutocompleteList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have to use a Virtual(on screen) keyboard on a asp:textbox which has a AjaxControlToolkit's 
automcomplete attached to it, the virtual keyboard I use is the jQuery keypad plug in:  http://keith-wood.name/keypadRef.html , but I have some problems with combining these two:

1. Typing in the virtual keyboard does not
   trigger the Autocomplete list.
2. When the textbox has
   autopostback=true if you click
   anything on virtual keyboard the
   textbox loses its focus and posts
   the form.

Does anyone knows that on respond to what events the autocomplete list activates?
and also I need to know how to prevent textbox from losing its focus when a button on virtual keyboard is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) JavaScript is setting the values and JavaScript does not trigger the autocomplete list from popping up. [and I doubt there is anyway to trigger it with JavaScript]

2) Clicking on the "keyboard" removes focus from the textbox and presto, the blur event fires and submits the form. [You would have to code your own autopostback=true] 
Basic idea is to add a timeout that calls `document.forms[0].submit()` and if the focus is added back to the textbox before the timeout fires `clearTimeout()`

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("yourElementId");
textbox.blur = function(){ this.timer = window.setTimeout( function(){ document.forms[0].submit(); }, 100 ) };
textbox.focus = function(){ if(this.timer) window.clearTimeout( this.timer ); };
```